# Relational model for ERD

Tags: erd

I have an ERD that I have developed relational model for. I just wanted to know if there are any errors in my relation model. I have listed the relational model below. I have a picture of the ERD.

```
PHYSICIAN (DRID (PK), NAME, SPECIALTY, PRESCRIPTION(FK))
PRESCRIPTION (PRESCRIPTIONID(PK), DRID(FK), DRUGID(FK), PATIENTID, DRUGDOSAGE)
DRUG (DRUGID(PK), DRUGNAME, DRUGMANU, DRID)
ORDERS (DRUGID(PK), PRESCRIPTIONID(FK))
```

[image: CLICK TO VIEW ERD]

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues in your ERD:

- Why does `Prescription` have a double-bordered box? It's not a weak entity set, it's identified by its own attributes.
- Instead of showing `Patient ID` as an attribute of `Prescription`, draw a relationship between `Prescription` and `Patient`.
- The ternary relationship `Orders` allows different physicians to prescribe drugs on the same prescription. Two binary relationships (many-to-one from `Prescription` to `Physician`, and a many-to-many between `Prescription` and `Drug`) should work better. In fact, your relational model almost does this already.
- Should each prescription record only one `Drug Dosage`? I would place this attribute on the suggested binary relationship between `Prescription` and `Drug`.

As for your relational model:

- If you include `PRESCRIPTION` in `PHYSICIAN`, this creates a functional dependency `DRID -> PRESCRIPTION`, in other words, each physician is associated with a single prescription. This is independent of `PRESCRIPTIONID -> DRID` in the `Prescription` table, which properly represents the binary relationship I suggested above.
- If you include `DRUGID` in `PRESCRIPTION`, this creates a functional dependency `PRESCRIPTIONID -> DRUGID`, in other words, each prescription is associated with a single drug. This is independent of the association between drugs and prescriptions in the `ORDERS` table.
- If you include `DRID` in `DRUG`, this creates a functional dependency `DRUGID -> DRID`, in other words, each drug is associated with a single physician. The physician for each drug in a prescription can be determined by joining `PRESCRIPTION` with `ORDERS`, no need to try and record it per drug.
- `ORDERS` should use a composite primary key `(DRUGID, PRESCRIPTIONID)` to represent a many-to-many relationship. As it stands, each drug can be associated with a single prescription.

I hope that helps.